# "Error: Don't know how to add RHS to a theme object" when saving theme formatting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get this "`Error: Don't know how to add RHS to a theme object`", when I try to save the following theme formatting in R:

```
# my_theme
my_theme <- theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=20, vjust = 0.55,
hjust = 0.99, colour = "black", family = "Eurostile"),
plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#DCDCDC"),
panel.background = element_rect(colour = "#DCDCDC"),
axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 20)) +
labs(caption="Graphics: XYZ\nSource: ABC")
```

Why do I get an error message?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi welcome to stackoverflow. You cannot change labels within the theme call, nor can you save a theme with labels that's why you get that error. This happens because labs() is not a theme. Before saving the theme, ggplot checks if the theme is a theme and returns that error if it isn't.

```r
is.theme(labs(caption="Graphics: XYZ\nSource: ABC"))
[1] FALSE
```

Save the theme and then add the labels separately.

```r
my_theme <- theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=20, vjust = 0.55,
                  hjust = 0.99, colour = "black", family = "Eurostile"),
                  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#DCDCDC"),
                  panel.background = element_rect(colour = "#DCDCDC"),
                  axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 20))

# assuming you plot is saved as p

p + my_theme + labs(caption="Graphics: XYZ\nSource: ABC")
```

That saves the theme and then you can add the labels to your plot when you add the theme. You can also save labels to the plot object p with the calls to ggplot and geom etc.

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks a lot. Have a nice day/evening!